# Great companies using FPA as cost estimation

Tags: estimation, fpa

Anyone know if great enterprises (Google, Oracle, SAP) uses Functional Point Analysis to estimate software building effort?

Comment: Since you're Brazilian too, Petrobras used to employ FBA as a cost estimation tool. I'm not sure it still does.

Answer (score 1):

The [IFPUG](http://www.ifpug.org) [Membership Survey](http://www.ifpug.org/membership/IFPUG%20MC%20-%20Membership%20Survey_Final_Analysis_Results_April09_Members_V1.0.ppt) will tell you a little bit. Still, when I see a company like "IBM" in that survey, I am guessing it is Global Services (their consultancy). Maybe some product teams use it but most of the members of this organization at least are consultants / service providers who are selling The Methodology along with Their Services.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for a fairly good-sized pharmaceutical company that used it, but that's the only time I've seen or heard of it used.  It seemed like a reasonable methodology to me, but rather time-consuming and probably expensive (the guy who analyzed my systems was an external IFPUG-certified consultant).